# Android - Bitmap from URL added to rootview

Tags: android

I'm having a bit of trouble pulling a bitmap from a url. I used an example from another question here on Stack, but it will not load the image. Here is the code:

```
public class Image extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://cogadget.com/cogadget/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Android-Logo-50x50.jpg");
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");


    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");

    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

I'm attempting to populate an ImageView with a bitmap from url. I can connect to the internet on my emulator, but in the logcat it tells me it can't establish a connection. I also set permissions in the manifest for the internet. I'm dumbfounded by what is probably an easy fix.

Comment: What @Quanturium answered is a start. But you really should post your logcat to see what issues you're stumbling on.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run a network operation (http connection) on the UI Thread. You should take a look at threads & asynctasks : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Also, I will definitely post the logcat tomorrow when I get back to work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the topic as solved when your bug is fixed

Comment: Was on vacation for a week. I'm back on the case now. The threads and processes page is practically my desktop background atm.